# Is it safe if I decide the DbConnection class by trial and error?

Tags: c#, database-connection, connection-string

Suppose that I have a connection string (in fact it will be a user entry). Using this string I want to create an appropriate `DbConnection` class. It would be either an SqlConnection, or OleDbConnection or OracleConnection (maybe another one in the future).

Would it be safe if I follow the following procedure?

For each possible connection class, I will create it and then open and close the connection.

- If it throws an exception i will try next class
- If it does not throw an exception, then it is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This strikes me as a bad idea, especially since you don't specify why you expect one of these to fail and what the reason is to use the next connection. What if it's a valid SQL connection string, but the db is simply unreachable? It wouldn't make any sense at all to try to connect to an Oracle db at that point.

A better way would be to let them select the provider type, then give the user a form with only the connection string properties they are allowed to change (with proper validation).

Answer (score 0):

It would be not safe because you give an attacker the possibility to bruteforce all your database connections at once.